# Image Processing - "non maximum suppression" vs "local maximal"

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision

In image processing texts, there are often algorithms that are described as non-maximum suppression. My question is: what is its difference between finding the local maxima value?

Comment: The main difference is that the former considers the gradient direction. The latter does not care about this. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13659517/non-max-suppression/13840446#13840446, for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Non-max suppression is typically encountered in two contexts: edge detection and local maxima detection.

In the context of edge detection, it refers to a thinning algorithm specialized for images of gradient magnitude.

In the latter context, it is equivalent to local maxima detection in its classical meaning (not morphological minima, etc.), where pixels which are not greater than their neighbors are set to zero.

Comment: Another example: in object detection, after detecting an instance of an object in an image, algorithms often perform non-maximum suppression to remove spurious evidence due to the detected object.  When continuing to process the image to find additional instances, there's less likelihood of a duplicate detection occurring.